# Integration Services error - "There is a potential ... in the ProvideComponentProperties"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I got this error message when trying to configure an Excel data source using the Source Assistant in SSIS 2012.  The message is:

*The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.  Could not initialize the component.  There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.*

Thought I'd share the answer which worked for me.

[image]

I believe the problem arises when you install SQL Server 2014 on top of SQL Server 2012, even if you do this as a completely separate installation.

Answer (score 4):

I repaired SQL Server 2012, and this got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue after installing SQL 2016 CTP3. Cleared up in 2012 once going through a 'repair' cycle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I installed SQL 2016 and was getting the same error. I went along and installed SSDT for 2016 and opened up Visual Studio 2015 and selected Business Intelligence as my project template.

[image: Sql Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015]